# Classification of fundamental domains of a fuchsian group

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, fuchsian-groups

Let $G$ be the (2,3,7) triangle group. We can see it as symmetry group of (2,3,7) tiling of the hyperbolic plane or symmetry group of $[3^7]$ tiling of the hyperbolic plane. This contains translations, rotations, and reflections.
From the comments, I understand that the set of translations need not be a subgroup of $G$.
Now suppose $H$ be a discrete subgroup of $G$ such that the quotient surface is the compact orientable surface of genus $g$. Then how to distinguish fundamental domains of $H$ for different presentations of $H$.
I want the number of distinct $[3^7]$ tilings on the orientable, compact surface of genus $g$. Is it possible to get this by classifying fundamental domains of $H$?

Comment: This is the same as being torsion-free and contained in the oriented motion group (of index 2). "What will be the generators" is not a very clear question, a group has many generating subsets and "generator" is senseless (or just a way to refer to an element of a given generating subset).

Comment: By last line I mean can we get a finite generating set? what will be the minimal number of elements required in the generating set of the translation subgroup?  The oriented motion group contains rotations also.

Comment: I wrote "torsion-free". For a discrete group of isometry this precisely discards the presence of rotations.

Comment: The answer to your question (minimal size of a generating subset) depends on the topology of the quotient surface. To answer more precisely, one should be more specific how the subgroup is given.

Comment: I want to know about the subgroup of $G$ containing only translations i.e group of translations. It is not given. The surface is the hyperbolic plane, not any quotient surface.

Comment: The set of translations need not be a subgroup. Or if you mean a subgroup consisting of translations, there are many (uncountably) such subgroups. (It might be an English issue: if you write "the subgroup", it means that you have one specific subgroup in mind.)

Comment: I wrote "quotient surface". Once you have a torsion-free discrete group of isometries, you get a quotient surface (quotient of hyperbolic plane by the given group).

Comment: OK, I realized that set of translations need not form a group. I have edited the question

Comment: Dear KAK, welcome to MO. I am a little worried that this question might get flagged for being unclear, but you might like looking at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/99375/are-any-two-dirichlet-domains-for-a-fuchsian-group-comparable?rq=1 which gets at some of the questions you are bring up.